# MySQL: something is wrong with my SELECT FROM IN syntax

Tags: sql, mysql

```
SELECT * FROM `objects` WHERE (user_id IN ('7,8,12,9') AND visibility IN ('0,1'));
```

but it only returns the stuff corresponds to the second array's first element.
So it returns the same as like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `objects` WHERE (user_id IN ('7,8,12,9') AND visibility IN ('0'));
```

(I swapped the two values (of the visibility arg) and completely different set of results was returned.  What I want, is both of results in one Query.

It's doing the same thing for the first array too. Only using the first value.

I would like the results from ALL the values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to quote each value if its a string:

`SELECT`objects`WHERE (user_id IN ('7','8','12','9') AND visibility IN ('0','1'));`

Or of youre actually dealing with integers you could do:

`SELECT`objects`WHERE (user_id IN (7,8,12,9) AND visibility IN (0,1));`

Also where is your `FROM` clause?

Comment: If user_id is an integer, you shouldn't need ' around the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Your "IN" clause is wrong.  It should be `user_id in (7,8,12,9)` or, if userid is character, `user_id in ('7','8','12','9')`